Two Azure Gateways possible with Firewall?
I have a hub and spoke architecture. One of the spokes should get it´s own VPN Gateway. I know that I can´t have a gateway and use the remote gateway option.
If my Hub has a firewall, can I just add a route to traffic on-premises from my spoke goes to the firewall, and the firewall will forward to the gateway so that I don´t have to use the "use remote gateway" option"?
Thank you

According to Microsoft architecture and best practices  in a hub spoke you place the vpn in a network hub,not in a spoke https://petri.com/how-to-architect-an-azure-firewall-with-a-vpn-gateway/
